# Unit Tests with @StringRes

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

How do I create a unit test for a method that annotates an argument with `@StringRes`  (i.e. `someMethod(@StringRes int someStringRes)`?. When I try to put in an arbitrary int for the test it throws a compiler error.

Comment: How are you running this test -- as a standard JUnit test or as an Espresso or Robolectric test? If one of the latter, presumably the body of the method does something Android-specific with the resource identifier, and you should supply an actual string resource. If the method _doesn't_ treat it as a resource identifier, why are you bothering with `@StringRes`?

Comment: Yes, it's just JUnit and the body of the method uses that arg to return a String in the resources file. It does work when I supply an actual String resource int (`R.string.some_string`) but it slows down the test considerably b/c relies on a res file

Comment: In that case, what do you expect to happen if you supply some arbitrary int? Surely at that point the test will crash. Can you post the body of the test or a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?